# automaticly refreshing excel sheets

Tags: c#, excel, resources, auto-update

I made a small console application that refreshes all the excel files in the same directory the program is in.
Its works perfectly well on the pc in wrote it on, but when I use it on a normal-client windows pc it does not even start.

Is there anything that needs to be installed, in order to make it work ?

code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CNTExcelUpdate_Invisible
{
    class Program
    {
        static string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            updateDirectory(path);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public static void updateDirectory(string path)
        {
            int amount = 0;
            string[] files;
            files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            amount += files.Count();

            int counter = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

                    if (fileName.Substring(0, 2).Equals("GK"))
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file,
                        0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                        true, false, 0, true, false, false);
                        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                        excelWorkbook.RefreshAll();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        excelApp.Quit();
                        excelApp = null;
                        excelWorkbook.SaveAs(file, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                        //excelWorkbook.Close();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
                        excelWorkbook = null;                        
                    }
                    counter++;

                    Console.Write(counter.ToString() + "/" + amount.ToString() + " Dateien verarbeitet");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler bei der Verbindung: \r\n" + e.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly "does not work" mean? WHat happens? What is the error?

Comment: Thats the point. it does simply not work. there is no error. there is nothing that tells me what happens. I included messageboxes to display the exceptions, but there are none.

Normally the console shold open´. you'll see a an integer (total sheets) an another int that is count up as it processes the sheets.

But there is noting. the console does not open up.